# UICollectionViewCell delegate won't fire

Tags: swift, delegates, uicollectionviewcell

I'm obviously doing something wrong but unable as of yet to determine where. I setup the cell as follows:

```
protocol PropertyPhotoCellDelegate: class {
    func deletePropertyPhoto(cell: PropertyPhotoCell)
}

class PropertyPhotoCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    weak var propertyPhotoCellDelegate: PropertyPhotoCellDelegate?

    let deleteButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        let image = UIImage(named: "delete.png")
        button.setImage(image, for: .normal)
        button.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = true
        button.isHidden = true
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleDeleteButton), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }()

        var isEditing: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            deleteButton.isHidden = !isEditing
        }

    }
```

I've omitted setting up the cell views. Here is the selector

```
@objc fileprivate func handleDeleteButton() {
    propertyPhotoCellDelegate?.deletePropertyPhoto(cell: self)

}
```

In the UICollectionViewController, I assign the delegate

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: kCellId, for: indexPath) as! PropertyPhotoCell
        cell.photoImageView.image = photos[indexPath.item]
        cell.propertyPhotoCellDelegate = self

        return cell
 }
```

This hides or shows the delete button on the cell for all the cells in view

```
override func setEditing(_ editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)

    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.isEnabled = !editing

    if let indexPaths = collectionView?.indexPathsForVisibleItems {
        for indexPath in indexPaths {
            if let cell = collectionView?.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? PropertyPhotoCell {
                cell.deleteButton.isHidden = !isEditing
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And finally, conforming to the protocol here

```
extension PropertyPhotosController: PropertyPhotoCellDelegate {

    func deletePropertyPhoto(cell: PropertyPhotoCell) {

        if let indexPath = collectionView?.indexPath(for: cell) {
            photos.remove(at: indexPath.item)
            collectionView?.deleteItems(at: [indexPath])
        }
    }
}
```

I tap the `UICollectionViewController` `Edit` button and all the cells show the delete button as expected. Any of the cell's `delete` button highlights on tap, but I don't see the `delegate` getting called.

Comment: everything seems fine, could you please provide a sample project, so that I can point out the mistake.

Comment: Have you confirm delegate of Collectionview?

Comment: *"I've omitted setting up the cell views."* - that may be the part that doesn't work. Show that code. And confirm with us whether `handleDeleteButton` is being called or not when the button is tapped.

Comment: A common practice to such situations is to put a `breakpoint`, see the `object/property` state at that point. Repeat until you reach the exact line of problem.

Comment: Sample project here https://github.com/jpatrickmc/PhotosCollectionSample

Answer (score 0):

When the delegate is assigned in the UICollectionViewController, also set the selector for the cell.

```
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: kCellId, for: indexPath) as! PropertyPhotoCell
    cell.photoImageView.image = photos[indexPath.item]
    cell.propertyPhotoCellDelegate = self
    cell.deleteButton.addTarget(cell, action: #selector(cell.handleDeleteButton), for: .touchUpInside)
    cell.deleteButton.isHidden = true
    return cell
}
```